# Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method

Tags: android, android-cursor

How to resolve given error? It happens when I try to refresh cursor from actionbar and sometimes when I try to delete again after long click on list item.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String QUERY_SELECTALL = "SELECT * FROM " + RjecnikDB.TABLE;
private RjecnikCursorAdapter adapter;
private RjecnikDB dbRjecnik;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    refresh();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.search_bar) {
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.refresh) {
        refresh();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void refresh() {
    dbRjecnik = RjecnikDB.getInstance(this);
    db = dbRjecnik.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SELECTALL, null);
    adapter = RjecnikCursorAdapter.getInstance(this, cursor);
    adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
}
```

WordsListFragment.java

```
public class WordsListFragment extends Fragment {
private final String QUERY_SELECTALL = "SELECT * FROM " + RjecnikDB.TABLE;

private RjecnikCursorAdapter adapter;
private RjecnikDB dbRjecnik;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.words_list_fragment_layout, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    fabAddWord = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabAddWord);

    dbRjecnik = RjecnikDB.getInstance(getActivity());
    db = dbRjecnik.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SELECTALL, null);
    adapter = RjecnikCursorAdapter.getInstance(getActivity(), cursor);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_ID));

            DiscardDialogFragment newFragment = new DiscardDialogFragment(_id);
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "discard");
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void changeCursor() {
    dbRjecnik = RjecnikDB.getInstance(getActivity());
    db = dbRjecnik.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SELECTALL, null);
    adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
}

public void deleteOnLongClick(int id) {
    db = dbRjecnik.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(RjecnikDB.TABLE, RjecnikDB.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
}

public class DiscardDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    int colID;

    DiscardDialogFragment() {}
    DiscardDialogFragment(int colID) { this.colID = colID; }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Izbriši riječ?")
                .setPositiveButton("IZBRIŠI",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                deleteOnLongClick(colID);
                                changeCursor();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        "Riječ je izbrisana iz baze", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("OTKAŽI", null);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea to grasp this changeCursor or refresh in one class, I tried many ways, but always it was errors.

Comment: it is because you may calling cursor.close() and after that using cursor gives such error. Please Post Database class code. You can refer here for better database management http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-sqlite-database/

Comment: I have not any cursor.close() call.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same error when returning to my app (from another app, which my app opened).

The solution for me was to replace my `spinnerAdapter.changeCursor(cursor)` code with `spinnerAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that we both had similar issues. I had a listener on a CheckBox in each list item. The listener was firing while the cursor was closing. Post your code for RjecnikCursorAdapter or you can test the listeners yourself. Check the listeners set in the code above or any set in RjecnikCursorAdapter.bindView or RjecnikCursorAdapter.getView.

This comment is incorrect:

> I have not any cursor.close() call.

adapter.changeCursor(cursor) closes the old cursor for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in my case clean and rebuild the project worked for me .
In addition i even deleted the app data in my mobile and changing the 
adapter.close()  to  adapter.swapCursor(cursor);